# My Update method is shown as unused, yet I'm coding within it

Tags: unity, c#

I'm doing a game lesson to get basic player movement working using Unity "[Lesson 2.1: Player Positioning](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/lesson-2-1-control-player-bounds-with-if-then-statements?labelRequired=true&pathwayId=5f7e17e1edbc2a5ec21a20af&missionId=5f71fe63edbc2a00200e9de0&projectId=5cdcc312edbc2a24a41671e6#5cbf6dfeedbc2a16f31319ad)". I started with creating the public variables and getting the axis and the horizontal movement. The issue started with the if statement. The main idea is to use the if statement to keep the player inbounds and prevent the player from going off the side of the screen with an if-then statement. But it is not working at all; it just goes right and disappears all around the map. I've compared my script with theirs, and it's the same.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
 public float horizontalInput;
 public float speed = 10.0f;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     if (transform.position.x < -10)
     {
         transform.position = new Vector3(-10, 
         transform.position.y, 
        transform.position.z);
     }
     horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.right);
  }
 }
```

[image: Unity Editor]
[image: Code]

Comment: What do you mean by "shown as unused"?

Comment: Like if I weren't using the method. But as I read the comment below is always called, as long as it is name Update() and my class is a MonoBehaviour so now everything is ok.

Comment: Sounds like you've titled this question after the wrong symptom then. I recommend editing your question so the title describes what's going wrong in-game.

Comment: Could you try to make your Update() method print something inside ? For example, can you call the method Console.Writeline() inside Update() to see if it prints something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not the same as in the tutorial. Step 4 in the tutorial uses `horizontalInput` in the `Translate`. If you don't use the input of your player, of course your character is not reacting to what you tell it to do. Your line 18 should be

```
transform.Translate(speed * horizontalInput * Time.deltaTime * Vector3.right);
```

Unused code or variables should be colored gray, not a darker shade of pink. Update() is always called, as long as it is named Update() and your class is a MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Thank you, I was typing fast and forgot the important part of the code. I'll be more careful next time.